# Cannot load css/js with relative path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've get a html with css & js like this in an ROR project

```
/public/foo/index.html  
/public/foo/js/main.js  
/public/foo/css/main.css
```

and in the index.html conclude js & css with relative path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>  
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and I add the following to `route`

```
match '/foo', :to => redirect('/public/foo/index.html')
```

So now I can access the index with `0.0.0.0/foo`
but of course cannot load css & js

so how to load css & js without edit the path in index.html?

Do I have to move css & js to another position?

Comment: Your path should be like 'foo/js/main.js' and 'foo/css/main.css' because all these files are under 'foo' folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's best to stick with rails standard and put the js and css under their respective app/assets directory (javascripts or stylesheets)